# What to change in sql connection apart from connection string when moving database server to Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-3

My application uses ASP .NET MVC 3. We have a database hosted in Windows 2008 Server. My client is upgrading database servers to Windows 2012 or Windows 2016 but in Azure Cloud Environment. Apart from changing connection string and key, what are other areas i need to look into to avoid issues in application?

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, please help mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to set firewall rule for your client ip, details are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#manage-server-level-ip-firewall-rules-using-the-azure-portal).

By the way, you can also easily get the connection string from azure portal like below:

[image]